# heightForRowAtIndexPath setting height for wrong row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a weird problem with the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function.
I need the height for the 3rd row to be higher, but it always sets the height for the next (in this case the 4the) row.

I'll explain:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  int height = 40;
  if(indexPath.row == 3) height = 120;
  NSLog(@"cell %i [height = %i]", indexPath.row, height);
  return height;
}
```

It logs this: (seems to be good)

```
       cell 0 [height = 40]
       cell 1 [height = 40]
       cell 2 [height = 40]
       cell 3 [height = 120]
       cell 4 [height = 40]
       cell 5 [height = 40]
       ...
```

And it looks like this:
[image: heightForRowAtIndexPath wrong height]

** (to be clear: the gray row is not a section but a different cell style.)

Am I missing something badly or what could I do wrong?
Thanks!

As requested, I added the cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FrontendCell";
  int cellType = [[self.cellTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  switch (cellType) {
    case FRONTEND_CELL_TYPE_DETAIL:{
        cell = [[FrontendDetailTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.title.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.description.text = [self.descriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.price.text = [self.details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.price.text = [self.details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }break;
}
```

Comment: show `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Comment: change this if(indexPath.row == 2) height = 120;

Comment: I was wrong saying the 3the row needs to be higher. It's the 4the row. By however, it's always the next one that gets the higher size.. (I edited the question)

Comment: Darshan, I just deleted my answer on that. He updated the question already. We will have to see the code on cellForRowAtIndexPath and may be willDisplayCell

Comment: willDisplayCell is not used

Comment: What is self.cellTypes and FRONTEND_CELL_TYPE_DETAIL?

Comment: The tableview has different custom cell styles: self.cellTypes is an array containing the IDs of the requested cell types. It's all FRONTEND_CELL_TYPE_DETAIL (int 0) except for the first index of the array (2nd row = gray row in screenshot) That seems to be working. Also the correct text is showed in the correct cells, so I guess the arrays are correct..

Comment: I suggest to rely on data, rather than `indexPath.row`.. something like if([[self.cellTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] == FRONTEND_CELL_TYPE_DETAIL) return 120;

Comment: But that still uses indexPath.row? In the actual code I use the array containing the celltypes just like you demonstrate. But to show the problem I made a simpler version that clearly shows the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer below. Let me know if it works. I am going out for dinner now. If it does not work, you should upload a sample project to Github. If no one fixes the problem for you, I will fix for you later.

Comment: I'll have a look and try to get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, all works fine but not presented as we expect.

I mean the height is set to 120 for row3 but its design is shifted so it looks like the next cell has 120 height. Please try to select those cells, maybe selection background will be informative. Also try to play with cell design to clarify that

Comment: You sir, are a genius. And if feel embarrassed. The custom cells aren't designed dynamic so there is a gab after the larger cell. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a rough idea on where could be the problem. I believe there is a mix up between the custom cell and a normal cell. Since you have 2 different types of Cell, inside **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, you should do something like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier1 = @"FrontendCell";
    static NSString * cellIdentifier2 = @"NotFrontendCell";

    if(indexPath.row==1){
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
    }
    else{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];
    }

  //Other code

}
```

Make sure that you have another custom cell for **NotFrontendCell** on the storyboard.

Comment: See the screenshot, it's already started from `row0`. Already he set to 4th row, but it's appear in 5th row.. According to question, the gray color gap consider as one row.

Comment: Exactly. My explanation was incorrect tough, I need to actual 4the row to be higher.

Comment: The First Row = row0, Second Row = row1 (Empty without label), Third Row = row2.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I will delete this answer.

Comment: Alex Peda found the solution. Really stupid, it happens. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

provide list of self.cellTypes and implementations for it.
you may have mistaken there.